# Watir screenshot colours differ on different machines

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

We are testing a web at work using gem Watir and just recently noticed that screenshot colours differ from PC to PC. If I take a screenshot on my PC it differs in colour intensity from my colleagues PC (for example something like #068100 vs. #057400)

Can't find anything on this. Has anyone else experienced this?

**EDIT:**

Code sample

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.resize_to(800, 800)
browser.goto 'private-web.com'
browser.screenshot
```

CSS I can not share. But the colour difference is on a picture inserted using `<img src=xxx>`

Comment: to be sure you should show us some code but I would bet that has nothing to do with watir but with different hardare, have you tried a color picker tool to compare ?

Comment: I am using standard `browser.screenshot.png`, I just don't want to believe it is hardware related. Shouldn't the web always show colours the same way, when they are specified by hex? 
I am comparing colours using a colour picker and it is not monitor settings related. I know that.

Comment: can you publish the code and css where you use the colors ?

Comment: It is possible that the browsers of the 2 PC's have different colour settings. I found this about Firefox colour settings: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1171999 it's about image colours, but possibly there is also a configuration for css color rendering.